# Computer making beep sounds

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, boot

i left the computer downloading with IDM and told it to shut down when the download is finished, when i came back i pressed the power button and i  got 1 long beep and 2 short beeps then it keeps running but nothing appears on the monitor, so what do you guys think ?
Specs :

- motherboard gygabyte GA-P64A-D3
- processor i5 3330
- VGA galaxy GTX 560 SE
- Ram corsair 4x2 gb
- 450w thermaltake power supply

P.S. i don't know my bios manufacturer or version.

Comment: Check your motherboard manual for the bios beep code errors.  Bios manufacture isn't that important

Comment: Looks like a video card issue according to [the beep code](http://forum.giga-byte.co.uk/index.php?PHPSESSID=ej2eg95l49gqc8o00q2s1oqj37&/topic,2248.0.html)

Answer (score 1):

Video fail. Power down, unplug power cord, remove and reinsert the video card, reconnect cords, try again. If that does not resolve it, try a different video card.

Comment: yah but i bought it only 5 mouths ago !

Comment: @qadrology hardware can fail on day 1...

Comment: i did re inserted the video card and the computer is now working fine :D thank you very much :D but i wonder what caused that error ?!